# Adding Authentication to staging website using codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i need to add authentication to my staging website index page.Whenever the user tries to open the staging site it should show login page.Once user login then only he can see the website.I have tried added a code for displaying login page but it is displaying blank page not displaying any error messages as well.Here is my code.
As my website looks link will be for eg:staging.website.com
whenever the user tries to open this site it should ask login first.

Controller:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() 
        { 
            parent::__construct();              
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('index_model');
    $this->load->model('login_model');
        }
public function index()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in'))
    {
        $data['admin_details'] = $this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in');   
        $data['records2'] = $this->index_model->get_all_banners();
        $data['records7'] = $this->index_model->get_all_banners();           
        $data['mainpage'] = "index";
        $this->load->view('templates/templatessss',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

}

public function login(){        
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name','User Name','trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="ferror"> ','</span><br />');             
    if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){ 
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    else{
        $user_name = $this->input->post('user_name');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        if($this->login_model->login_user($user_name,$password)):
            redirect('welcome');
        else:
            $data['error'] = '<span class="ferror"> User Name or Password enter wrong. Please try again </span>';
            $this->load->view('login',$data);
        endif;   
    }   
}
```

view(login.php):

```
<?php

$form_attributes  = array('class'=>'admin_login_form', 'name'=>'admin_login_form', 'id'=>'admin_login_form', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data");
$user_name       = array('name' => 'user_name', 'id' => 'user_name', 'value' => set_value('user_name'),'class' =>'text');
$password = array('name' => 'password', 'id' => 'password','class' =>'text');
$submit = array('id' => 'login_details', 'value' => 'Login', 'name' => 'login_details');
?>

            <?php echo form_open('welcome/login',$form_attributes);?>
            <?php echo (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : ' ';?>
            <?php echo (isset($error)) ? $error : '' ;?>
                <?php echo form_label('User Name', $user_name['id']);?>
                <?php echo form_input($user_name); if(!$this->input->post('user_name')) echo form_error('$user_name');?>
                <?php echo form_label('Password', $password['id']);?>
                <?php echo form_password($password);?>
                <div class="sep"></div>
                <button type="submit" class="ok"><?php echo form_submit($submit);?></button>
```

Model(login_model.php):

```
class login_model extends MY_Model
{
function login_user($user_name = '', $password=''){
    $userdetails = array(
    'user_name' => $user_name,
    'password' => md5($password),
    );
    $this->db->where($userdetails);
    $query = $this->db->get('login_details');
    if($query->num_rows()):
        $user = $query->result();
        $sess_arry = array(
            'user_id' => $user[0]->user_id,
            'name' => $user[0]->name
        );          
        $this->session->set_userdata('admin_logged_in', $sess_arry);                    
   return true;
    else:
        return false; 
    endif;
}
}
```

Comment: open `index.php` file in your root folder and define `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');` . if it doesn't works `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and check the errors.

Comment: Not getting you.This should be added in index.php file in views.ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: you want to redirect user to login page in anywhere he goes?

Comment: Whenever any user tries to open my demo site it should ask to login first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in your Controller:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller { 
  function __construct() 
  { 
     parent::__construct(); 
     $this->load->library('form_validation'); 
     $this->load->model('index_model'); 
     $this->load->model('login_model'); 
  } 
   public function index() 
   { 
     if($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in')) 
     { 
       $data['admin_details'] = $this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in'); 

      $data['records2'] = $this->index_model->get_all_banners(); 
      $data['records7'] = $this->index_model->get_all_banners(); 
       $data['mainpage'] = "index"; 
       $this->load->view('templates/templatessss',$data);
    }
    else
    {
         redirect('welcome/login');
    }
```

I hope it will work for you!!

Comment: it's better to redirect user to login page. not load view

Comment: @MasoudTavakkoli Yes it's better to redirect instead of view.

Comment: @JayKareliya i tried with that as well not working getting as This page isn’t working

www.dev2.website.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: @user8001297 what url did you get after redirection?

Comment: @JayKareliya http://www.dev2.website.com/welcome/login getting same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147590/discussion-between-jay-kareliya-and-user8001297).

Comment: Any solution getting blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Change your else condition

```
else
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
```

To

```
 else
   {
        redirect('login');
    }
```

Comment: This page isn’t working

www.dev2.website.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: open` index.php` file in your root folder and define `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');` . if it doesn't works `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and check the errors

Answer (score 0):

**welcome class**

```
function __construct() 
    { 
        parent::__construct(); 
        $this->load->helper("url");
        if (!$this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in')){
              redirect(base_url("login"));
        }         
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('index_model');
        $this->load->model('login_model');
    }
```

**A login Class**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{

  function index(){
    if (isset($this->input->post())){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name','User Name','trim|required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="ferror"> ','</span><br />');             
if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){ 
    $this->load->view('login');
}
else{
    $user_name = $this->input->post('user_name');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    if($this->login_model->login_user($user_name,$password)):
        redirect('welcome');
    else:
        $data['error'] = '<span class="ferror"> User Name or Password enter wrong. Please try again </span>';
        $this->load->view('login',$data);
    endif;   
    }   
  }else{
       $this->load->view("login");
   }
}
```

this should working fine

Comment: Tried with this as well not working created a new login controller and copied my login function code in that not working

Comment: This page isn’t working www.dev2.website.com redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: getting blank page